# Selenium - Java - How can I pass website address from one test to another

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm quite new in programming and `Selenium` and I am sure I am missing something quite basic. I have got project using **Page Object Pattern** and **Page Object Factory**. I have got few classes - one for one webpage. I have got tests for those pages too (of course 1 test = one class). My webpages & tests:

1. Login page
2. List item

User account page

In order to get to user account page, I need to log in on login page. For now I can't reach user account page, because for those two tests I have got the same `driver.get("webpage address")`. But I can't write address for second page because it is unknown. Can I somehow pass "`result`" from first test to second, so I can start it?

Comment: Does this [example](http://www.protechskills.com/testing/automation-testing/selenium/selenium-webdriver-script-login) help?  If you really want to separate tests instead of using @Before to login then make driver a static class variable.  When you login the home page is displayed and driver already points you there.

Comment: it is better make your tests independent (if you pass result from test1 to test 2 then test2 is dependent on test1). also remember that the order or test run is not guaranteed.